# Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_pandas'

Tags: python, heroku

I am getting this error while trying to deploy my Flask Application that works locally to Heroku platform.
My python version is 3.8.8

Given Requirements.txt, Please help

```
pandas==1.2.4
numpy==1.20.1
requests==2.25.1
Flask==1.1.2
jsonify==0.5
gunicorn==20.1.0
dill==0.3.4
scikit_learn==0.24.2
sklearn==0.0
```

Log on Heroku :

```
2021-06-25T09:28:45.141310+00:00 app[web.1]: return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
2021-06-25T09:28:45.141310+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn_pandas'
2021-06-25T09:28:45.141604+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-25 09:28:45 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-06-25T09:28:45.399214+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-25 09:28:45 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8 was terminated due to signal 15
2021-06-25T09:28:45.488197+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-25 09:28:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-06-25T09:28:45.488354+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-25 09:28:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-06-25T09:28:45.602110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-06-25T09:28:45.689594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-06-25T09:28:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-25T09:28:53.371200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=carsellingprice012.herokuapp.com request_id=ad50ea6f-f606-4e4c-8e07-b3fb947f0bb1 fwd="137.97.120.236" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-25T09:28:54.143122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=carsellingprice012.herokuapp.com request_id=0179fab5-224b-4436-b575-c0fb4e33ee75 fwd="137.97.120.236" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sklearn-pandas to the requirements.txt